# AngularJS + Bootstrap flexBox incompatible?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, flexbox

Attempting to have "flex" as the display should line the elements together, but it does not for some odd reason.

I tested my work for the past 4 days on simple syntax. Double checked for syntax error, misspellings, and broke down all css to core html elements when testing this.

Decided to open a new directory to test my base knowledge of flex box, same setup with parent and children divs, and it works. The only thing different is that I did not connect Angular CDN.

The layout on both files are the same except for the "{{}}" for ng-repeat pushing out strings from a object.

I looked on google, but I cannot find a precise answer.

Answer (score 1):

Angular is a javascript frontend framework and do not interfere with any css at all. 
This mean that it is **NOT** incompatible with a flex box.

I use flex for some of my projects too and it's working like a charm. So you do something else wrong